# Apache creates file: how to control permissions

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, file-permissions

My Django app via Apache creates log files: log.txt

The Owner and group of this file is "www-data"

```
owner rwx
group r
all r
```

My python app has no read/write permissions to this log file. But I need the python app to have this permissions.

Now it is easy to manually change permissions, but I need the file to have the correct permissions when it is created. How can I do that?

```
my goal:
add python user to group www-date  (what is the name of the python user?)
and then:
Owner rwx
Group rwx
all r
```

Comment: you can start your python-app with the user www-data privileges, thus you will be able to work with files owned by www-data. ex, `sudo -Hu www-data /path/to/your/app`

Comment: I understand from your comment that there is no python user. It is always the user that calls the python script.

Comment: solved it using umask 002 in /etc/apache2/envvars

Answer (score 0):

You may use [os.chmod()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod) to control the permissions of a given file, after creating the file you can execute:

```
os.chmod("/path/to/file", 0o775)
```

The first argument being the path and the second argument is the flag for permission to be granted, you may also access the flags from `stat` module.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can only do this if I modify the source code of the python logger module. Beause the application does not know when a new logging file is created (revolving file versions).